# Apache tomcat with virtual ip

Tags: tomcat

I have server with  *physical ip* and *virtual ip* that setup by network administrator. inside the server i install `Apache tomcat 7.0.29` and create a web application. when i run wget `http://<physical ip>:8080/xxx` or `http://<localhost>:8080/xxx`, i can get the page but not with wget `http://<virtual ip>:8080/xxx` and it throws *error* as below

```
Connecting to <virtual ip>:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.
```

The *os* of the server is `redhat`.

how to get `http://<virtual ip>:8080/xxx works`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your two best choices:

1) Get a static IP (this is *not* as "necessary" as many tend to assume it is)

... OR ...

2) Use a DNS server that can update its records whenever the IP address changes (Windows Active Directory excels at this kind of thing)

If neither of these are an option, you can:

3a) Write a "cron" job on the Tomcat server that periodically calls "http:/www.whatismyip.com" (or something similar) to get your current IP address, and 3b) have the script send you an e-mail (or something similar) whenever it detects the address has changed.

'Hope that helps